# How do I install the Operating System of an ISO file to a hard drive partition the same way I can install it to a USB?

Tags: hard-drive, boot

I'm using Windows x64 (different versions), and I'm looking for freeware or open-source. I'm trying to dualboot ThinClient (Linux-based) alongside Windows. I already have the software to use it as VM or extract to USB; burn to disc; simply extract contents. But is there a sort of Wizard to extract it to a partition and automatically create a BCD entry afterwards?

Comment: Are you trying to installing Windows with Linux? Make a bootable drive and install it. You can't install it just by "extracting".

Answer (score 2):

No. Due to the nature of how a bootloader works, you cannot mount an ISO directly and boot from it. Either you need to use a VM where there is a layer before the bootloader, or you use software such as Rufus to burn the ISO directly to an USB stick, then boot from that USB stick.

Comment: Hello. I'm not trying to boot from the ISO. I want to extract the OS from the ISO and correctly add a boot loader entry to the BCD. Like I said, I want to boot into ThinClient, a **LINUX-based** operating system, meaning it should use the same booting conditions as Linux Ubuntu, Debian, etc... (knowing I want to boot using a **BCD** instead of GRUB) But I can easily install Windows, because it has its own installation wizard to get it onto the hard drive from the CD or USB key. Can't do that installing ThinClient. I need a sort of "Rufus" that extracts to hard drives instead of removable ones.